# Is it possible to make an image move with the cursor when it gets near, and have collision?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a maze game. I got provided with how I would make an image not able to enter a div with jQuery. I also have a code with the image following the cursor. In the second code, I made it so that the image would only go to the mouse if it was a certain distance away. With the collision, the code from the second code got messed up, and now the image teleports to the cursor, instead of how I want it to act. How can I fix this? I am flexible if you need to use pure js or jquery UI. I highly prefer jQuery.

## jQuery from first code:

```
function collisionCheck(ax,ay) {
            var collide = false;

            var aminY = ay;
            var aminX = ax;
            var amaxX = aminX + $('#image').width();
            var amaxY = aminY + $('#image').height();

            $('.maze').each(function(){

                collide = false;

                var bminY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
                var bminX = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft(); 
                var bmaxX = bminX + $(this).width();
                var bmaxY = bminY + $(this).height();

                if (amaxX < bminX) collide = true; // a is left of b
                if (aminX > bmaxX) collide = true; // a is right of b
                if (amaxY < bminY) collide = true; // a is above b
                if (aminY > bmaxY) collide = true; // a is below b

                if (!collide) {
                    return collide;
                }
            });
          return collide;
        }
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          startMove = true;
      var cursorY = e.pageY;
            var cursorX = e.pageX;
          if (collisionCheck(cursorX, cursorY)) {
        $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
        $("#image").css({
          left: e.pageX,
          top: e.pageY
        });
          } else {
        $('html').addClass('showCursor');
          }
        });

        $("#drop").mouseenter(function(){
            alert("Success");
        });
});
```

## jQuery from the second code:

```
var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var DIFF_SNAP = 10;
  var DIFF_UNSNAP = 100;
  var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
  var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
  if (!startMove && Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_SNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_SNAP) {
    startMove = true;
    $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
  } else if (startMove && !(Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_UNSNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_UNSNAP)) {
    startMove = false;
  }
  if (startMove) {
    $("#image").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('showCursor');
  }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  startMove = false;
})

$("#drop").mouseenter(function(){
 if(startMove)
   alert("Success");
});
```

1st jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8pc3u7t9/1/
2nd jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/26/

Comment: When I open the second fiddle the image only start following my mouse when it gets close to it, it doesn't teleport? Could you explain a bit more since it seems to work fine here?

Comment: Ok. The image teleports to my cursor when my cursor is any distance away from the image on the first fiddle. On the second fiddle, the image only teleports to the cursor if the cursor is a certain distance away.

Comment: I want the second one to apply to the first one.